# Live HTML Editor Google Chrome Extension Permanent

Tags: html, chrome, html-editor, live-preview

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can permanently edit the HTML of a website, and apply the changes to the HTML on website load. I would like this extension to work on any website I choose, and I am not looking for a website creator, just an editor like the Chrome developer tools, but permanent and I would prefer it to update changes live.

There are some of these extensions for Chrome that do live editing, but they only work for CSS. Here is an extension for css: [Magic CSS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/live-editor-for-css-less/ifhikkcafabcgolfjegfcgloomalapol/related?hl=en)

Thanks :)